# Как ограничить картинку размерами родителя, при относительных размерах flex-родителя?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Делаю горизонтальное меню в шапке и отчего то картинка ведущая на главную выводится в своем полном размере(
Макс-хай 100% лишь растягивают менюшку(

Я хочу что бы логотип был высотой с менюшку. На странице эбаут у меня получилось так сделать с одну строку, на странице exp с одноименным css я пытаюсь отказаться от фиксированного размера меню, что бы его высота определялась количеством строк кнопок.
Архив: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aplZoRqspLx58snAnLWYRU-2NG9INCb2/view?usp=share_link
Тому кто исправит код на правильный с комментариями - скромный донат.
По правильному коду мне будет конечно легче разобраться с темой хтмл-цсс.

Ссылка на макет в котором видно как должно быть
https://www.figma.com/file/DbFZjw0g7QL9Z6hAz1DE3f/warl0?node-id=0%3A1&t=yav6NY9wLmDTMryE-1

[image: пример как выходит плохо]

[image: как должно выглядеть при увеличении меню на вторую строку кнопок]

[image: пример как должно выглядеть лого при одной строчке меню.]

Неудачная попытка сделать меню без фиксированой высоты:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Protoblock</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/exp.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="viewbox">
    <header>
      <div class="header-box flex">
      <a href="index.html" class="header-logo">
        <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">
      </a>
      <nav class>
            <ul class="list-reset menu top-menu">

            <li class="menu-item menu__item-li">
                <a class="menu_item" href="#">
                  ПУБЛИКАЦИИ ↓
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item-li top-menu_selected">
                <a href="#" class="menu_item">
                  ОБО МНЕ
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item-li">
                <a href="#" class="menu_item">
                  ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТЬ
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item-li">
                <a href="#" class="menu_item">
                  ПОРТФОЛИО
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item-li">
                <a href="#" class="menu_item">
                  КОНТАКТНАЯ ИНФОРМАЦИЯ
                </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

```
html  {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after    {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body    {
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0;
    font-family: PT sans;
}



.header-box {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

.header-logo  {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo  {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.menu  {
  /* position: absolute; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-item  {
  padding: calc(0.5rem + 1.3vw) calc(0.1rem + 1.4vw) calc(0.5rem + 1.3vw) calc(0.05rem + 0.5vw);
}

/* globe */

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

/* .list-reset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
} */

.link-reset {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Без вашего html и css нам вам нечем помочь (телепаты на выезде), но если вам поможет правильный ответ (два правильных ответа из огромного количества вариантов), — flex-shrink или flex-basis.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, когда вас просят предоставить ваш код, то выкладывать его нужно здесь, чтобы люди могли живьём его видеть (некоторые из нас знаете ли умеют читать), как есть, а не упакованные архивы невесть где.
Во-вторых, у вас там такая каша из абы чего, что мозг сломать можно. Ради интереса, чтобы всё-таки понять что вам нужно, я убрал весь ваш CSS и написал необходимый минимум как должно быть. И, может это и есть ответ на ваш вопрос, добавил одно единственное правило для адаптивности изображения `img.cart-ava` и всё прекрасно заработало.

Однако, исходя из вашей текущей html-вёрстки и постановки вопроса и превьюшки из поста одно расходится с другим. В частности блок `.cart` содержащий изображение и вступление. Текстовая часть принципиально никак не может растягиваться на всю ширину экрана, а согласно .flex будет одинаковой шириной с изображением.

Проделал всю эту работу за вас и потратил кучу времени лишь для того, чтобы, вы понимали как не надо делать в вёрстке, и как надо делать, когда вас просят предоставить код. И, вдруг кто-нибудь глядя на уже очищенную от шлака вёрстку всё ещё захочет вам помочь. У меня уже нет на это настроения.

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.viewbox {
    display: flex;
}

.cart {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

img.cart-ava {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


.menu.index-menu {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

.menu_item.cart__menu__item a {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}
.menu__item a {
    line-height: 5rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewbox">
    <div class="cart">
        <div class="cart-pic">
            <img class="cart-ava" src="https://i.imgur.com/Oc61Mw9.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="cart-text">
            <p class="cart-pre">
                Фрактальный авангардист, экспериментатор, а так же тот еще выдумщик.<br>
                Да и в принципе, забавный персонаж.
            </p>
            <h1 class="cart-title">Варло</h1>
            <p class="cart-p">
                Более десяти лет занимаюсь культурной деятельностью в различных ее проявлениях.
            </p>
            <p class="cart-p">
                Я полон идей и проектов по направлению ко всеобщему благу, но в данный момент остро нуждаюсь в
                финансовом росте.
                Поэтому активно изучаю дизайн и веб-разработку.
            </p>
            <p class="cart-p">
                Как всегда, открыт к сотрудничеству и взаимодействию.
                Ну и конечно, горю желанием обрести коммерческих заказов.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu index-menu">
            <!-- внутри ul всегда идет список li потом только ссылка a -->
            <li class="menu__item cart__menu__item">
                <a href="#">
                    ПУБЛИКАЦИИ ↓
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item">
                <a href="about.html">
                    ОБО МНЕ
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item">
                <a href="#">
                    ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТЬ
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item">
                <a href="#">
                    ПОРТФОЛИО
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item">
                <a href="#">
                    КОНТАКТНАЯ ИНФОРМАЦИЯ
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>


<div class="public">
    <div class="public-conteiner">
        <div class="post">
            <time class="post-data">2022.11.09</time>
            <h2>Лента публикаций ниже первого экрана</h2>

            <p>
                А ведь реально уже на чтото становится похоже. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                elit. Soluta minima ullam cum tenetur laboriosam sapiente quis? Eligendi animi tempora adipisci
                neque. Est minima at consectetur blanditiis natus expedita dignissimos necessitatibus.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. я там ещё попутно убрал "избыточную" ерунду в меню в виде класса к тегу `a class="menu_item"`

```
<li class="menu__item">
   <a href="about.html" class="menu_item">
      ОБО МНЕ
   </a>
</li>
```

Comment: так в аве карты все в порядке. извините конечно что код не тут написал, еще не разобрался с сайтом. ваш код у себя попробовал и чтото совсем ничего не заработало. Вот если что линк на то как должно выглядеть. https://www.figma.com/file/DbFZjw0g7QL9Z6hAz1DE3f/warl0?node-id=0%3A1&t=yav6NY9wLmDTMryE-1 (вопрос у меня только по поведению меню, как его подружить с лого не задавая фиксированого размера)

Comment: "ваш код у себя попробовал и что-то совсем ничего не заработало".  Не знаю, что вы у себя пробуете, если можно и здесь посмотреть. Опять же во-первых, коль у вас в фигме есть образец, то почему сразу не "пнули" нас в конкретную картинку? И почему не делаете это сейчас? Ваша задача как была непонятна таковой и остаётся. С учётом того, что нам требовалось от вас конкретный код и конкретное пожелание, вы по-прежнему продолжаете "мусорить" избыточной информацией. ВОПРОСЫ: какую картинку из трёх мы адаптируем? https://i.imgur.com/pdc2PwF.png Какой конкретно файл из трёх? Научитесь ставить вопросы.

Comment: вот сейчас все перепилил...
по вашему скрину - два правых это как раз и есть то как долнж выглядеть при меню в одну строку кнопок и в две. левая картинка это главная, с ней все ок.